# Need help to Develop Clock functionality for different time zones in android?

Tags: android

I developed a **sample clock (Analog)** application to display the time. Now my application shows the current time of my mobile. I wish to improve it for **showing world times**. Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge in this, can any one guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code i used to display all cities times.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**timezone.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timezone_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timezone_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The class files are...

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.practice.secondhand;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected static final int UPDATE_UI = 0;

    TimeZoneAdaptor timezoneAdaptor = null;
    List<TimeZoneData> timezonelist = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        timezonelist = new ArrayList<TimeZoneData>();
        timezoneAdaptor = new TimeZoneAdaptor(this, R.layout.timezoneview,
                timezonelist);

        setListAdapter(timezoneAdaptor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String[] listItems = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

        TimeZone timezone = null;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE, MMM d, yyyy h:mm a");
        Date now = new Date();

        for (int index = 0; index < listItems.length; ++index) {
            timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(listItems[index]);

            format.setTimeZone(timezone);

            timezonelist.add(new TimeZoneData(getDiaplayName(listItems[index]),
                    format.format(now)));

            timezone = null;
        }
    }

    private String getDiaplayName(String timezonename) {
        String displayname = timezonename;
        int sep = timezonename.indexOf('/');

        if (-1 != sep) {
            displayname = timezonename.substring(0, sep) + ", "
                    + timezonename.substring(sep + 1);
            displayname = displayname.replace("_", " ");
        }

        return displayname;
    }

    public class TimeZoneAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<TimeZoneData> {

        List<TimeZoneData> objects = null;

        public TimeZoneAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<TimeZoneData> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

            this.objects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ((null != objects) ? objects.size() : 0);
        }

        @Override
        public TimeZoneData getItem(int position) {
            return ((null != objects) ? objects.get(position) : null);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;

            if (null == view) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.timezoneview, null);
            }

            TimeZoneData data = objects.get(position);

            if (null != data) {
                TextView textName = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.timezone_name);
                TextView textTime = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.timezone_time);

                textName.setText(data.name);
                textTime.setText(data.time);
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**TimeZoneData.java**

```
package com.practice.secondhand;


public class TimeZoneData {
        public String name;
        public String time;

        public TimeZoneData(String name,String time) {
                this.name = name;
                this.time = time;
        }
}
```

**TimeZoneAdaptor .java**

```
public class TimeZoneAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<TimeZoneData> {

    List<TimeZoneData> objects = null;

    public TimeZoneAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<TimeZoneData> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != objects) ? objects.size() : 0);
    }

    public TimeZoneData getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != objects) ? objects.get(position) : null);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) TimeZonesList.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.timezoneview, null);
        }

        TimeZoneData data = objects.get(position);

        if (null != data) {
            TextView textName = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.timezone_name);
            TextView textTime = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.timezone_time);
            textName.setTextSize(18);
            textName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            textName.setText(data.name);
            textTime.setText(data.time);
            textTime.setTextSize(15);

        }

        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however I'm having one small issue preventing me from compiling. Its in the file TimeZoneAdaptor.java and its the line: LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) TimeZonesList.this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); The issue is: **TimeZoneList cannot be resolved to a type**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like TimeZoneAdaptor.java file is not required. The same class has been defined inside the MainActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs%28%29) to get the names of all available time zones, and [getTimeZone](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) to instantiate each time zone. And then use a TimeZone object to construct a [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object. After setting that up with the right fields, you call its [getTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) method to get a [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) object which you can then format in displayable form with a [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html).

It’s all rather confusing, really...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. could you please post any example code for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The above is great except for the last line in onCreate()

```
    setListAdapter(timezoneAdaptor);
```

It is not in any of the other classes and it is not in the Java or Android Libraries.  Anyone have any ideas on how fix this since the code can't be compiled as is?  I am going to continue to work at and if I figure out something I will update.

**Edit**

Needed to extend ListActivity instead of Activity.  Its still odd that a search of the Android Library for the setListAdapter() method turned up nothing.

Comment: I got it working.  It was very helpful in figuring out what all the TimeZone Ids are.  Now that I know what the time zone ID is I am trying to get a working digital clock in my App that will show GMT time no matter the system time is.  Not so easy.